# No location fix on GPS - Android

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I copy pasted the following code from this [link](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/) . No location info was shown when i used a active device instead of emulator. Even Gps is enabled

```
public class UseGps extends Activity

{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {

        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);

        setContentView (R.layout.main);

        /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */

        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener ();

        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

    }

    /* Class My Location Listener */

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

    {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged (Location loc)

        {

            loc.getLatitude ();

            loc.getLongitude ();

            String Text = "My current location is: " + "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude () + "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude ();

            Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled (String provider)

        {

            Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled (String provider)

        {

            Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged (String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

        {

        }

    }/* End of Class MyLocationListener */

}/* End of UseGps Activity */
```

Comment: did you add the permissions ?

Comment: yes i did. still no change.

Comment: http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/    same manifest only i copied

Comment: same means full copy paste ? or you have change his package with yours?

Comment: package com.example.gps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

Comment: This is the code before class starts

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct. If you haven't forgotten to add permissions, perhaps, your device cannot find satellites. Just try to test it outside the building.
Or just try to use

**EDIT:**

```
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(mlocManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true), 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

instead of LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.

Comment: shows error. criteria and enabled only cannot be resolved to a variable.. even if i go out of home and tried too, there was no change.

Comment: When google maps are working well in my location, why not this application? both uses GPS rite?

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok.
Maybe your device really cannot find satellites. Try to run this code with fake gps application like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=ru

Comment: My google maps can access the gps. but why not the code?